# Stash embed not working

Tags: stash, parse-order, parse

Hoping someone can help as this has been driving me crazy for 2 days now...

For some reason I just can't get this to work in a template:

```
{stash:embed:layouts:product}
```

When I view the page it simply shows that code above. I'm using EE 2.9.2 and Stash 2.6.5.

I have the following structure;

EE templates from file:
/_templates/base/_pages.group/product.html (which contains the above embed)

Stash templates:
/_templates/base/_stash/layouts/product.html

In my site's index.php I have the following;

```
// Stash
$assign_to_config['stash_file_basepath'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/../_templates/base/_stash/';
$assign_to_config['stash_file_sync'] = ('ENV' == 'prod') ? FALSE : TRUE; // set to FALSE for production
$assign_to_config['stash_file_extensions'] = array('html', 'md', 'css', 'js', 'rss', 'xml');
$assign_to_config['stash_static_basepath'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/../public_base/static/';
```

I can't figure out what is going on. The stash tags just doesn't seem to parse/process and I have this setup exactly the same on another site. Stash looks to be working as it is setting the stash cookie.

I would be really grateful if anyone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appeared that the install of the latest version of Stash installed multiple of the 2 Stash hooks in the extensions table. Reinstalled the extension and it then correctly added the 4 hooks. However, I had to change the priority of one of the template hook's because another module was causing a problem. Thanks to Mark Croxton for helping cure my sanity with this one.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the Stash *extension* is installed on the extensions page in the control panel. The Stash extension converts `{stash:embed_name}` into the more "normal" `{exp:stash:embed name="embed_name"}` in the background, so it could be that for some reason this is not happening.

Comment: Hey James. I'll post the solution. Mark Croxton helped me resolve the issue via Slack.